# What is this 'slow-moving grey smoke' Skyrim player effect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: screenshot of effect described below]

In *Skyrim Special Edition*, this effect is permanently attached to my player. If I can find the right code I know I can remove it with `player.addspell/player.removespell`, but after lots of searching, I haven't been able to identify the right one.

It's a slow-moving grey smoke, maybe a slight greenish tinge, with faster swirling lighter grey parts.

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: Is your character a Vampire or Werewolf? The smoke looks like the transformation effect for those characters and you might be stuck in a "mid-transformation" state.

Answer (score 2):

**Try resolving the problem using a 'Cure All' batch file.**
These files list all known active effects from the base game and DLC (and the Wet & Cold and Skyrim Immersive Creatures mods), preceded by the `player.sme` command (which stands for 'Stop Magic Effect' on 'player'), and can be executed using the in-game console.

You can find an archive file with these batch files under *Solution 4* on [this page](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/872861-tutorial-removing-unwanted-magic-effects-from-the-player/). [Here](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=40779) is a direct link (you need a (free) account in order to download). The file was created by NexusForums user *LubitelSofta*.
Be sure to take off all your (enchanted) gear beforehand.

Instructions as per the Nexus forum thread:

> - Extract the files to your Skyrim root folder (not the data subfolder).
> - Edit the Dawnguard, Dragonborn, or WC or SIC batch files (if necessary) so that every shader or effect ID matches your load order (see above).
> - Start the game.
> - In the console type `bat <filename>` (without quotes), e.g. `bat DBMGEF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all applied spells by using player.DispelAllSpells, I believe. Note that this will also remove blessings and apparel effects, so you will need to unequip and re-equip armor to re-apply the effects from armor.

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to work with this one.